# PHP: why do I get "Array" instead of its content

Tags: php

When I want to print the content of an Array, I always get the string "Array" instead of the content.

I've also tried: `implode(",", $myArray);`

but still I get "Array" rather than the content itself

Comment: Does `$myArray` contain nested arrays?  Can you add the output of `var_dump($myArray)` to your question?

Comment: Add some more code and you could get some help.

Comment: Are you storing another array within that one? You may have to call implode() recursively.

Comment: What would you like the output to look like? (Serious question, will help us craft an answer.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `print_r()` to recursively print arrays.

Answer (score 2):

[`implode()`](http://us.php.net/implode) takes a maximum of two arguments:

```
 string implode ( string $glue , array $pieces )
```

Try [`var_dump()`](http://us.php.net/var_dump), [`var_export()`](http://us.php.net/var_export) or [`print_r()`](http://us.php.net/print_r) instead:

```
var_dump($myArray);
var_export($myArray);
print_r($myArray);
```

Comment: Where did he try to use `implode()` with more than two arguments?

Comment: Ah, I misread the question as two empty strings: `implode('','', $myArray);`

Answer (score 1):

```
var_dump($theArray);
```

This prints out the array in nice tabbed format, with both the keys / indices, value types and values shown.